# Decompiler attack

Tags: ida, decompilation, exploit, vulnerability-analysis

I noticed that [Hex-Ray have been keeping reward to people who find "security vulnerabilities" of IDA-Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/bugbounty.shtml).:

So here is my question, how come a decompiler can have "security vulnerabilities"? And more importantly, is there any real-world example to attack decompilers or disassemblers? Or can I perform certain kind of "malware evading attacks" by abusing the decompiler bugs?

Comment: How about a vulnerability that, given a suitably crafted malware, results in execution of code in the malware being studied ?

Comment: For examples, see https://www.hex-rays.com/vulnfix.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you won't be happy if, while analyzing a malware, a certain pattern in the executable binary makes Hex-rays connect to an evil server somewhere in the World with your account and download a payload on your system...

And, yes, there have been some examples where security analysis software have been pinpointed with security threats. The last I have in mind are on Ghidra:

- [CVE-2019-16941](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-16941/)
- [CVE-2019-13623](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2019-13623/)

See also [here](https://threatpost.com/bug-in-nsas-ghidra/148787/).